Why Are Node Voltages Not Equal in Transformer Circuit with k=1 in LTSpice?

In the first transformer circuit, where the coupling coefficient k = 1, the effective circuit seen by the first source (V1) of the second circuit with source V2 is shown below. In this equivalent circuit, V3 represents V1 and V4 represents the effective V2.

However, when I plotted the time-domain voltage at Node1 and Node2, I observed that:

Node1 voltage = 5V (Blue)
Node2 voltage = 0V (Green)

Since the transformer with k = 1 should ideally transfer energy perfectly, shouldn't the voltages at Node1 and Node2 be equal? Why am I seeing a voltage difference between them? Could there be something wrong with the circuit setup, or am I misunderstanding the ideal transformer behavior in the time-domain simulation?

Click here to get the LTspice file.

Look at what you have done and ask yourself if this is at all reasonable: -

An inductance of 1 μH at an angular frequency of 1 rad/sec has an impedance of precisely 1 μΩ so, how can you expect to see a sensible voltage developed across the primary given that the primary source is in series with 5 Ω.
If you wanted to, you could dredge the depths around +/- 1 μV and see a waveform but honestly, I think you should be using a sensible frequency like 1 kHz and inductor values in the henry region to make any form of useful comparison.
At the end of the day, a transformer winding still behaves like an inductor.

Thank you so much! I adjusted the inductors to 1 and 4, the plots are almost equal..
